# button.visible = true unexpected error

Tags: c#, windows

I'm working on a project in which i have a timer. When the timer is over I'm doing some instructions and I'm setting visibility of a button to true.
This line result to an error

```
"Invalid parameter" in Program.cs at line
Application.Run(new Main());
```

I have no idea how a simple change on the visibility of a button can cause an error here.

Here is the code :

```
private void timerDuring_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timeLeft > 0)
    {
        timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
        labelTime.Text = timeLeft +"";
    }
    else
    {   
        TimerDuring.Stop();
        labelTime.Visible = false;
        VCapture.Dispose();
        VCapture = null;

        capture.Dispose();

        CamImageBox.Visible = false;

        String pathVideo = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "video.avi");
        WMP.Visible = true;
        WMP.URL = pathVideo;   //Emplacement de la video apres la capture
        WMP.uiMode = "none";
        WMP.settings.setMode("loop", true);
        WMP.Ctlcontrols.play();   // chaque image a recup

        btnDecoupe.Visible = true; // ERROR caused  HERE
        btnReplay.Visible = true;  // ERROR caused  HERE
   }   
}
```

And the Program.cs where the error is indicated by Visual Studio:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Point d'entrée principal de l'application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Main());
    }
}
```

When I change `Visibility` to `false` it works, error is thrown only when I change it to true.

The name of my form is "Main.cs"

Comment: Which timer are you using ?

Comment: c# Timer control named TimerDuring

Comment: Is it a Windows.Forms.Timer, System.Threading.Timer or a System.Timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only be manipulating controls on the UI thread. You can do that by calling [Control.Invoke()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        btnDecoupe.Visible = true;
        btnReplay.Visible = true;
    }));
```

Do the same for setting them to false. Any time you want to change something about a control in a different thread, such as in a timer event.